# Defining infinte operations over not metric spaces

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces

The question may seem a little weird at first but what I'm asking is on how to rigorously define things of the form $$V_n\in\mathrm{Vec-}k:\bigoplus_{n=1}^{\infty}V_n$$ and generally expressions of this kind were one isn't working over metric spaces. The reason I mention metric spaces is that say the operation $l:M^2\to M$ for some metric space $M$ then it's easy to define $$l_{n=1}^{\infty}s_n\overset{def}{=}\lim_{k\to\infty}l_{n=1}^k l_n$$ with the limit defined using the metric on $M$. Sorry if this is a dumb question just am not sure how one would go about defining this. Thanks to everyone who replies.